# how to disable executing user-data by cloud-init

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I am making a new AMI in EC2 and want to disable it running anything that could be put in user-data when launching (or rebooting) from this AMI.  I looked at the existing `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` and `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/*` but do not see where this is enabled (so maybe it is on by default).  **How can I reconfigure cloud-init to not allow this or even allow this to be re-enbled?**  I suspect I also need to disable `#cloud-config`.  Do I need to disable the whole cloud-init package to achieve this?

*edit:*

I will be using Amazon Linux *and* Ubuntu in various AMIs.

*edit2:*

It looks like I need to disable *all* of `user-data`.  Maybe that will be easier.

*edit3:*

I do want to be able to access the `user-data` in *my* scripts.

Comment: It depends highly on your usage of cloud-init functionality, but the quickest answer to your question would be no to use the cloud-init package on your AMIs - it's a big framework and insecure.  You can extract the user-data from the metadata endpoint using curl if you need that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my current hack — not too elegant, but it works:

```
patch /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/stages.py <<EOF
@@ -469,7 +469,6 @@
     def consume_data(self, frequency=PER_INSTANCE):
         # Consume the userdata first, because we need want to let the part
         # handlers run first (for merging stuff)
-        self._consume_userdata(frequency)
         self._consume_vendordata(frequency)

         # Perform post-consumption adjustments so that
EOF
```

Comment: looks good.  i added a call to `sed -i` in my build script to comment out that line.  running tests now.

Comment: testing the test AMI now.  ran an Amazon Linux instance in parallel, both with `halt -fp` in a script in user-data.  the Amazon Linux one has self terminated already ... looking good so far.

Comment: yay! works in 4 regions.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way to do this is create a file named **cloud-config.txt** in **/var/lib/cloud/instances/{your-instance-id}** , with the following content:

```
#cloud-config   
# from 1 files
# cloud-config.txt

--- cloud_final_modules:
-   - scripts-user
    - never 
...
```